# how to print at same line using end parameter?

Tags: python

I'd like to print at same line for print statement inside a for loop using end= parameter. not sure which end parameter i can use.

For example, in below, for each time's print, only need to change str(i) and str(result), everything is the same.

```
for i in range(10):
   result=i**2
   print('iteration is'+str(i)+' with result of '+str(result))
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `not sure which end parameter i can use.`?

Comment: `'\r'` can move back to the start of the line, if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: `print(my_str, end='')`

Comment: Thanks Johnny, using '\r' work. here is my new code:   for i in range(1000000):
   result=i+10
   print('iteration is '+str(i)+' with result of '+str(result),end='\r').  Can you provide the solution so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: @roudan I think this will cause the next printed line (from somewhere else in the code) to override this print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty end parameter and go back the length of the previous print

```
L=0
for i in range(3):
   result=i**2
   my_str = 'iteration is'+str(i)+' with result of '+str(result)
   print('\b'*L + my_str, end='')
   L= len(my_str)
```

Comment: There's no reason to print more than one `\r` (carriage return) here. Maybe you are thinking of `\b` (backspace).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, you're right. I was thinking of \b. Thx